# Laravel modules what to do next?

Tags: php, laravel

PS C:\Users\DELL\Laravel\projet1> **php artisan module:make Customers**

Created : C:\Users\DELL\Laravel\projet1\Modules/Customers/module.json
Created : C:\Users\DELL\Laravel\projet1\Modules/Customers/Routes/web.php
Created : C:\Users\DELL\Laravel\projet1\Modules/Customers/Resources/views/index.blade.php
Created : C:\Users\DELL\Laravel\projet1\Modules/Customers/Resources/views/layouts/master.blade.php
Created : C:\Users\DELL\Laravel\projet1\Modules/Customers/Config/config.php
Created : C:\Users\DELL\Laravel\projet1\Modules/Customers/composer.json
Created : C:\Users\DELL\Laravel\projet1\Modules/Customers/Resources/assets/js/app.js
Created : C:\Users\DELL\Laravel\projet1\Modules/Customers/Resources/assets/sass/app.scss
Created : C:\Users\DELL\Laravel\projet1\Modules/Customers/webpack.mix.js
Created : C:\Users\DELL\Laravel\projet1\Modules/Customers/package.json
Created : C:/Users/DELL/Laravel/projet1/Modules/Customers/Database/Seeders/CustomersDatabaseSeeder.php
Created : C:/Users/DELL/Laravel/projet1/Modules/Customers/Providers/CustomersServiceProvider.php
Created : C:/Users/DELL/Laravel/projet1/Modules/Customers/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php
Created : C:/Users/DELL/Laravel/projet1/Modules/Customers/Http/Controllers/CustomersController.php
Module [Customers] created successfully.

PS C:\Users\DELL\Laravel\projet1> **composer dump-autoload**

Generating optimized autoload files

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump

> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

Error

Class 'Modules\Customers\Providers\CustomersServiceProvider' not found

at C:\Users\DELL\Laravel\projet1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php:208
204▕      * @return \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider

```
205▕      */

206▕     public function createProvider($provider)

207▕     {
```

➜ 208▕         return new $provider($this->app);

```
209▕     }

210▕ }

211▕
```

1   C:\Users\DELL\Laravel\projet1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php:144
Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository::createProvider("Modules\Customers\Providers\CustomersServiceProvider")

2   C:\Users\DELL\Laravel\projet1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php:61
Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository::compileManifest()
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
PS C:\Users\DELL\Laravel\projet1>

Comment: Why you copied your whole terminal commands, and why you didn't ask a question?

Comment: i answered myself again in the comment section, and this is my first stackoverflow problem

Answer (score 0):

this is what i did ;

Need to add "Modules": "Modules/" psr-4 part in your root composer.json file:
“psr-4”: {
“App\”: “app/”,
"Modules": "Modules/"
}